# If I buy a Nexus one in Best Buy can I use it for develop applications?

Tags: android

I want to start Mobile Phone development, but I am very very new to this area, I have 3 choices: iPhone, Nexus One and Windows Phone. I believe Nexus one atracts me more. But I have never bought a smart phone. My questions is: If a buy one Nexus One from Best Buy store, can I use it for developing Android applications?

I appreciate your help, nobody helps me with this question and I am a novice in smart phones.

Thnak you

Edgar

Comment: @George...that's a very random set of comments there.

Comment: @DA: You are right. Maybe this is better:.... In my opinion, you have made a good decision starting with Android. a) iPhone is a more restricted product (only Apple hardware, only AT&T provider last I heard) and it also requires a Mac for you to get started developing. b) As far as I know, Windows Phone is just not as good of a product as Android or iPhone.

Comment: well, still a lot of subjectivity there. All 3 platforms are very robust. There's pros and cons to each, though. Some of have bigger market share, some appeal to a slightly different demographic, etc. It's going to really depend on the type of application one wants to build.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part you do not need a device to start doing mobile development.  You can download the Android SDK complete with an emulator here:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

If you're not sure which kind of development you'd like I'd recommend downloading the toolkits for all the major ones, trying them out, and then decide.

- [Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- [Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Phone/)
- [iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)
- [Blackberry](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/)

Comment: Totally agree with this reply. Try out android programming with the sdk and emulator. if you want to continue further after wetting your hands, then buy a new device!

Answer (score 2):

You don't develop mobile software ON a mobile device. You use them to test.

If your choice is Android vs. Windows vs. iOS, then you need to decide what kind of software you will be writing.

For native apps, all 3 use very different development platforms (java vs. .net vs. objective-c).

If you're going to go the HTML5 + Phonegap route, then it really doesn't matter. And you really don't need a physical device anyways...you can always test on simulators.

If you want to do ANY app dev for iOS, though (be it native or phonegap) you WILL need OSX on a desktop/laptop computer.

Answer (score 0):

First decide what operating system you want to work on as DA suggested. If you have decided to develop applications for Android then iPhone and Windows phone is of no use to you.
Only those devices having Android Operating System you can use, Nexus One or Samsung GalaxyS are good options.
But before buying anything you can start developing applications as there is emulator provided which does most of the work that a device does.